# SVM with RBF: Decision values tend to be equal to the negative of the bias term for faraway test samples

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

Using RBF kernel in SVM, why the decision value of test samples faraway from the training ones tend to be equal to the negative of the bias term *b*?

A consequence is that, once the SVM model is generated, if I set the bias term to 0, the decision value of test samples faraway from the training ones tend to 0. Why it happens?

*Using the LibSVM, the bias term* b *is the* rho. *The decision value is the distance from the hyperplane.*

I need to understand what defines this behavior. Does anyone understand that?

Running the following R script, you can see this behavior:

```
library(e1071)
library(mlbench)
data(Glass)
set.seed(2)

writeLines('separating training and testing samples')
testindex <- sort(sample(1:nrow(Glass), trunc(nrow(Glass)/3)))
training.samples <- Glass[-testindex, ]
testing.samples <- Glass[testindex, ]
writeLines('normalizing samples according to training samples between 0 and 1')
fnorm <- function(ran, data) {
    (data - ran[1]) / (ran[2] - ran[1])
}
minmax <- data.frame(sapply(training.samples[, -10], range))
training.samples[, -10] <- mapply(fnorm, minmax, training.samples[, -10])
testing.samples[, -10] <- mapply(fnorm, minmax, testing.samples[, -10])
writeLines('making the dataset binary')
training.samples$Type <- factor((training.samples$Type == 1) * 1)
testing.samples$Type <- factor((testing.samples$Type == 1) * 1)
writeLines('training the SVM')
svm.model <- svm(Type ~ ., data=training.samples, cost=1, gamma=2**-5)
writeLines('predicting the SVM with outlier samples')
points = c(0, 0.8, 1,                         # non-outliers
  1.5, -0.5, 2, -1, 2.5, -1.5, 3, -2, 10, -9) # outliers
outlier.samples <- t(sapply(points, function(p) rep(p, 9)))
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testing.samples[, -10], decision.values=TRUE)
svm.pred.outliers <- predict(svm.model, outlier.samples, decision.values=TRUE)

writeLines('')                          # printing
svm.pred.dv <- c(attr(svm.pred, 'decision.values'))
svm.pred.outliers.dv <- c(attr(svm.pred.outliers, 'decision.values'))
names(svm.pred.outliers.dv) <- points
writeLines('test sample decision values')
print(head(svm.pred.dv))
writeLines('non-outliers and outliers decision values')
print(svm.pred.outliers.dv)
writeLines('svm.model$rho')
print(svm.model$rho)

writeLines('')
writeLines('<< setting svm.model$rho to 0 >>')
writeLines('predicting the SVM with outlier samples')
svm.model$rho <- 0
svm.pred <- predict(svm.model, testing.samples[, -10], decision.values=TRUE)
svm.pred.outliers <- predict(svm.model, outlier.samples, decision.values=TRUE)

writeLines('')                          # printing
svm.pred.dv <- c(attr(svm.pred, 'decision.values'))
svm.pred.outliers.dv <- c(attr(svm.pred.outliers, 'decision.values'))
names(svm.pred.outliers.dv) <- points
writeLines('test sample decision values')
print(head(svm.pred.dv))
writeLines('non-outliers and outliers decision values')
print(svm.pred.outliers.dv)
writeLines('svm.model$rho')
print(svm.model$rho)
```

Comments about the code:

- It uses a dataset of 9 dimensions.
- It splits the dataset into training and testing.
- It normalizes the samples between 0 and 1 for all dimensions.
- It makes the problem to be binary.
- It fits a SVM model.
- It predicts the testing samples, getting the decision values.
- It predicts some synthetic (outlier) samples outside [0, 1] in the feature space, getting the decision values.
- It shows that the decision value for outliers tends to be the negative of the bias term *b* generated by the model.
- It sets the bias term *b* to 0.
- It predicts the testing samples, getting the decision values.
- It predicts some synthetic (outlier) samples outside [0, 1] in the feature space, getting the decision values.
- It shows that the decision value for outliers tends to be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean *negative* of the bias term instead of inverse?

The decision function of the SVM is `sign(w^T x - rho)`, where `rho` is the bias term , `w` is the weight vector, and `x` is the input. But thats in the primal space / linear form. `w^T x` is replaced by our kernel function, which in this case is the RBF kernel.

The RBF kernel is defined as [image]. So if the distance between two things is very large, then it gets squared - we get a huge number. `γ` is a positive number, so we are making our huge giant value a huge giant negative value. `exp(-10)` is already on the order of 5*10^-5, so for far away points the RBF kernel is going to become essentailly zero. If sample is far aware from all of your training data, than all of the kernel products will be nearly zero. that means `w^T x` will be nearly zero. And so what you are left with is essentially `sign(0-rho)`, ie: the *negative* of your bias term.